# OKD unable to pull lager images from Internal Registry right after deployment of microservices through Jenkinsx

Tags: kubernetes, okd, jenkins-x

I am trying to deploy micro services in OKD through Jenkinsx and the deployment is successful every time.

But the Pods are going into "ImagePullBackOff" error right after deployment and comes into Running state after deleting the pods.

**ImagePullBackOff Error:**

[image: ImagePullBackOff Error]

**Events:**

[image: Events]

The images are being pulled from the OKD's internal registry and the image is of size "1.25 GB". And the images are available in the Internal Registry when the pod is trying to pull it.

I came across "image-pull-progress-deadline" field to be updated in the "/etc/origin/node/node-config.yaml" in all the nodes. Updated the same in all the nodes but still facing the same "ImagePullBackOff" error.

I am trying to restart the kubelet service but that fails with kubelet.service not found error,

```
[master ~]$ sudo systemctl status kubelet
Unit kubelet.service could not be found.
```

Please let me know if restart of kubelet service is necessary and any suggestions to resolve the "ImagePullBackOff" issue.

Comment: Try to execute `systemctl daemon-reload` before (re)starting your kubelet. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I tried that too and the command "systemctl daemon-reload" ran successfully but facing the same "kubelet not found" error.